# В чём Некорректность в записи пути к файлу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, scss

В SCSS: `background-image: url('./app/img/header/header-menu-bg.png');`

После компиляции в CSS-файле прописывается тот же путь, но он почему-то НЕ работает (пока не заменю его на относительный, с выходом на директорию вверх).

./ - вроде бы как путь от индексного файла, я думал, что универсальный).

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: ./ - это текущий каталог / - корень сайта

Answer (score 1):

Например, ошибка в сервере, не умеет он в такое.
проинспектируйте этот путь в браузере, например, попытайтесь открыть фоновую картинку в другой вкладке и посмотрите, что вам сгенерировало в качестве урла.
также можно попробовать задать base url, но тут могут быть бяки при переносе на другой домен.

Comment: Спасибо за полезную инфу